# How to convert normals to degrees?

Tags: java, vector, rotation, normals

I am working on a game and I am writing an `Entity` base class. Since many of the entities will behave like particles(2D) I want to use a normal instead of a rotation in degrees. However since I am using OpenGL I need to have the degree of the normal to rotate. What is the fastest way to convert from the normal to degrees and vice versa. I know that I can use trigonometric functions such as `atan2` `sin` `cos` etc, but I am pretty sure there is a faster method. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The normal is always 90 degrees from the surface. I'm not sure what you're after...

Comment: no its in two dimensions. ill make a diagram.

Comment: I might simply make a lookup table if I can't figure it out. ':P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're constrained to two dimensions and you're trying to convert a directional vector (x, y) to degrees from the x-axis, then `atan2(y, x)` is almost definitely going to be your fastest method, unless you're constraining the possible values of x and y to some pretty trivial cases. To get the degrees from the y-axis, just use `atan2(x, y)`, of course. This angle will be in radians. Multiply by 180/pi to convert to degrees. This should require a trivial amount of time.

The figure you're drawing suggests that `atan2(x, y) * 180 / Math.PI` will give you the results you desire.

Don't be concerned with speed unless you've profiled your code and have determined that there is a bottleneck in this calculation (which is unlikely).

Comment: Upvoted for the final paragraph, lots of people make that mistake.